# SFMC Data View Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, soql-injection

I have a query, I want to bring in all the Sends (for particular email) and opens. But in my query it only brings the matching  Opens. For example email sent to 1000 subscribers and total unique opens are 100, thus query returning 100 records. I want query should return 1000 records and then wherever subscriber matches for open it should pull in else let the field be blank.

Here is my query, (i already tried LEFT vs RIGHT join in 2nd join which is Open and send.

```
    SELECT 
 s.SubscriberKey as Email,
J.EmailName,

S.EVENTDATE AS SendDate,
O.Eventdate as OpenDate,
C.Eventdate as ClickDate

FROM 
[_Sent] S



LEFT JOIN [_Job] J ON S.JobID = J.JobID

LEFT Join [_Open] O ON S.AccountID = O.AccountID
AND                    S.OYBAccountID = O.OYBAccountID
AND                    S.ListID = O.ListID
AND                    S.BatchID = O.BatchID
AND                    S.JOBID = O.JOBID
and S.SubscriberID = O.SubscriberID
AND                    S.SubscriberKey = O.SubscriberKey


LEFT Join [_CLICK] C ON     S.AccountID = C.AccountID
AND                    S.OYBAccountID = C.OYBAccountID
AND                    S.ListID = C.ListID
AND                    S.BatchID = C.BatchID
AND                    S.JOBID = C.JOBID
and S.SubscriberID = C.SubscriberID
AND                    S.SubscriberKey = C.SubscriberKey




WHERE j.emailname = 'onboarding_phase_1_1_v2'

and 
(o.isunique = 1 or o.isunique is null)
and 
(C.isunique = 1 or C.isunique is null)

and
cast(s.EventDate As Date) = cast('2019-06-11' as Date)
```

Comment: I am assuming 'Email' is your primary key. You will need to pull that from _Sent (s) not _Open (O) as open will not have subkeys for any non opens. E.g. `s.SubscriberKey as Email`

Comment: I already made that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is the where clause `and o.IsUnique = 1`

If the subscriber doesn't have an open this would be null and not be included. It needs to be updated to `and (o.isunique = 1 or o.isunique is null)`

Comment: Good Catch... :) Thank you.

Comment: So after doing this.. now I can see their are various emails (subscriber keys) those are blank?

Comment: Gortonington comment answers this issue. You are using o.subscriberkey where you should be using s.subscriberkey

Comment: Yeah.. I think I am tried for the day :) ... U r right..

Comment: One last question... Here is my query...I made the chnages in query... in Updated question... 
THis time how do exclude the clicks those does not have the opens... In my results their are around 20 clicks those does not have associated opens....???

Comment: E-Mail Clients of Firewalls can block the Tracking Pixel that it will not be loaded from the receiver or the email client just does not open but shows a preview and you still can click. The open count is not a secure way to tell if somebody has actually opened an email. Several facts can make this metric unclear in both ways. Sometimes firewalls also click and open all emails they receive or block and rewrite links. Just to keep that in your mind